# How can I get a req.body from a form that is not undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

Whenever I submit a form with information it is returned as undefined. I have posted the code below. If I include the (enctype="multipart/form-data") in my form I dont receive anything for the body (req.body). However, if I dont include it I receive a body but the file processing does not work and the page just keeps loading.

```
app.post('/processupload', function(req, res) {
var date = new Date();
titles.push(req.body.pTitle);
descriptions.push(req.body.postDescription);
dates.push(date.toString());
file_names.push(req.body.fUpload);

console.log(req);

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files)
{
    if(err) return res.redirect(303, '/error');
}); 

form.on('end', function(fields, files)
{
    var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
    var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
    var new_location = __dirname + '/public/images/';
    fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name);
    res.redirect(303, 'home');
});
```

});

```
<form action="/processupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="uploadForm" name="postForm">
    <p align="center" id="pUploadForm" name="pPostForm"><label for="photoTitle">Photo Title: </label>
    <input type="text" id="photoTitle" name="pTitle"><br>

    <br><input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fUpload"><br>

    <br><label for="photoCaption">Photo Caption: </label><br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="photoCaption" name="postDescription"></textarea><br><br>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to access the form body via the `fields` object in the `form.parse` callback. You can't access it via `req.body` as this is not an [`express`](http://expressjs.com/)-style request object.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I created a project few weeks back that had photo upload. I used Angular and Node. But it should still work without Angular only using Node. I used multer npm package.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
var s3 = new AWS.S3(); 
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() }); //Save photo in memory

router.post('/processupload', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res, next){
  var bucketName = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
  var file = req.file;
  var filename = file.originalname;
  var ext = _.last(filename.split('.'))
  var keyName = uuid.v4() + '.' + ext;
  var url = process.env.AWS_URL + bucketName + '/' + keyName;
  var params = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: file.buffer, ACL: 'public-read' };
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
      return res.status(400).send(err)
    } else{
        console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
        console.log("The URL is", url);
        res.send(url)
    }    
  });
});
```

This helped me uploading images then gives me back the image url from the S3 Bucket. But you can handle that file as you want. Multer allows you to access to `req.file` so you can do whatever you need to do, in this example I created a unique id in order to get a url to send back to the front-end and therefore use it a source somehow. This is a form working with this code:

```
    <form action="/testupload" method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" multiple=false>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Something important that took a long time to debug though the `name="photo"` in the form must be reflected by the `upload.single('photo')` middleware. I hope this helps, there are so many ways go around this, this is just one.

Sources: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/UploadingObjectsintoAmazonS3.html